# Cisco ISE REST API to get the device information

Tags: mdm

I am working on an MDM(Mobile Device Management) feature where I need to find a relation between the device(I have Device's Serial Number/Mac address) and the user for whom this device is enrolled under the targeted MDM(e.g. any leading MDM Provider). All these MDMs are based on Cisco ISE. Now, Cisco ISE provides various APIs to fetch different kind of information, but I am not able to find the one I need. I referred to the following book to understand more about my question, but didn't get exactly what I need:Cisco ISE API Reference Guide 2.0.
I might be looking at wrong place or might have missed something. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is External RESTful Services APIs for Endpoints](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/2-0/api_ref_guide/api_ref_book/ise_api_ref_ers2.html#27975) for Cisco ISE 2.0. Maybe this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I used it. :)